# reformatting data into multiple columns in R

Tags: r, formatting

I am working in R. I have data that are currently in one long column and I need to parse it out in to different columns.

CURRENT FORMAT (all data appear in one column called var1)

```
var1
585                               00:40:01.530 --> 00:40:03.480
586                     Alex High School: Yeah. Again, Megan.
587                               00:40:05.970 --> 00:40:06.330
588                                  Alex High Five: Megan.
589                               00:40:08.190 --> 00:40:11.520
590 Charlie High School: Know how did with code Daniel go first.
591                               00:40:12.600 --> 00:40:12.810
592                                     Charlie High School: But
```

DESIRED FORMAT

```
585 00:40:01.530 --> 00:40:03.480   Alex High School: Yeah. Again, Megan.
                   
587 00:40:05.970 --> 00:40:06.330 Alex High Five: Megan.
589 00:40:08.190 --> 00:40:11.520 Charlie High School: Know how did with code Daniel go first.
591 00:40:12.600 --> 00:40:12.810 Charlie High School: But
```

Comment: The desired format isn't showing up the way i want it to. Basically I want the timestamp in one column and I want the text e.g., "Alex High School: Yeah, Again, Megan. to be in a second column.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that for every timestamp there is a text, then we could do:

```
data.frame(matrix(df$var1, nrow(df)/2, byrow=TRUE))

                            X1                                                           X2
1 00:40:01.530 --> 00:40:03.480                        Alex High School: Yeah. Again, Megan.
2 00:40:05.970 --> 00:40:06.330                                       Alex High Five: Megan.
3 00:40:08.190 --> 00:40:11.520 Charlie High School: Know how did with code Daniel go first.
4 00:40:12.600 --> 00:40:12.810                                     Charlie High School: But
```

If that is not the case, then you will have to reshape the data:

```
 reshape(transform(df, id = id <-cumsum(grepl("-->",df$var1)), time= ave(id, id, FUN = seq)), v.names="var1", dir="wide")
  id                        var1.1                                                       var1.2
1  1 00:40:01.530 --> 00:40:03.480                        Alex High School: Yeah. Again, Megan.
3  2 00:40:05.970 --> 00:40:06.330                                       Alex High Five: Megan.
5  3 00:40:08.190 --> 00:40:11.520 Charlie High School: Know how did with code Daniel go first.
7  4 00:40:12.600 --> 00:40:12.810                                     Charlie High School: But
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to use the second option. Can you explain a bit what ave() is doing in this case?